# How to include resources (js/css) that are bundled in a gem file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm confused...

I have installed a new gem file which packages a bunch of js ([rails-fullcalendar](https://github.com/bokmann/fullcalendar-rails)).

I now want to use this gem. So I added some

```
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

which I use with some js in my application

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar();
```

Problem is, it won't work since I don't have the proper js files. I added js includes in my layout like this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "fullcalendar.js" %>
```

But that makes little sense. There is no fullcalendar.js in my assets so the browser complains about missing js files. Where are theses js in the gem file? How do I include js from this gem file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a beginner, this was not obvious. Not even sure this is the best answer.

First, in your ***application.js*** add js from the gem:

```
= require fullcalendar
```

Then, in ***aplication.css*** add the css from the gems like this:

```
*= require fullcalendar
*= require fullcalendar.print
```

This file generates a CSS automatically when you start the server. So don't forget to ***RESTART THE SERVER*** (I didn't know I had to, so I cursed my computer many many times).

Life is wonderful once more!